# MVVM pattern and Storyboard iOS

Tags: ios, design-patterns, mvvm

Does somebody can explain me how to implement MVVM pattern, when project includes Storyboard?

In many examples I saw that I have to use `.xib` files. And `init` `ViewControllers` like this:

```
-(instancetype)initWithModelView:(ViewModel *)viewModel{

    self = [super init];

    if(self){

        _viewModel = viewModel;
    }

    return self;
}
```

But with Storyboard I cannot `init` `viewControllers`, storyboard does it for me.
Should I use properties instead?

i.e.

```
UINavigationController *nav = (UINavigationController *)[self.viewControllers objectAtIndex:0];
HomeViewController *hvc = (HomeViewController *)[nav.viewControllers objectAtIndex:0];
hvc.viewModel = viewModel;
```

self is `UITabBarController`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can initialize a `viewModel` property in `prepareForSegue:sender:` method of your `UIViewController`

Here is a link to a great sample MVVM app [C-41 by Ash Furrow](https://github.com/AshFurrow/C-41)

An example of a `viewModel` initialization in that app:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"showDetail"]) {
        NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];

        ASHDetailViewController *viewController = segue.destinationViewController;
        viewController.viewModel = [self.viewModel detailViewModelForIndexPath:indexPath];
    } else if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"editRecipe"]) {
        ASHEditRecipeViewController *viewController = (ASHEditRecipeViewController *)[segue.destinationViewController topViewController];
        viewController.viewModel = [self.viewModel editViewModelForNewRecipe];
    }
}
```

Comment: Hmm... Does this mean that in Swift the `viewModel` property of the view controller needs to be implicitly unwrapped?

Comment: I guess so. Here is a real world example of an MVVM app in swift (with storyboards): https://github.com/artsy/eidolon. They create view models inside view controllers (as `lazy var`), but they provide parameters in `prepareForSegue` via explicitly unwrapped optionals.

Comment: err... via implicitly unwrapped optionals.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way to handle navigation between views using **coordinator** or using **RX**.
This will have the separation of concern concept.